# How to make a recursive lambda function that takes 2 arguments not 1?

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion, lambda, std-function

I already know how to make a recursive lambda function that take one argument like calculating factorial of a number, but I try to make a recursive power function using lambda (as a practice), but taking 2 arguments in the function caused errors

this the code :

```
std::function <int(int)> power = [&](int a, int n)
{
    return (n<=1) ? a : a*power(a, n-1);
};
```

this line `return (n<=1) ? a : a*power(a, n-1);` gives these errors :

> ```
> error:   no match for call to '(std::function<int(int)>) (int&, int)'
> note:   candidate: _Res std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::operator()(_ArgTypes ...) const [with _Res = int; _ArgTypes = {int}]
> note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to use

```
std::function <int(int, int)> power = [&](int a, int n) { ... }
```

for the function to work with two arguments.

### Suggestions for improment:

#### Make sure you deal with `n = 0` correctly.

Use of

```
return (n <= 1) ? a : a*power(a, n-1);
```

is not right.  You will get back `a` when the function is called with `n = 0`.

Use

```
return (n == 0) ? 1 : a*power(a, n-1);
```

#### Use `unsigned int` for `n`.

```
std::function <int(int, unsigned int)> power = [&](int a, unsigned int n) { ... }
```

Then, you won't have to worry about the function getting called with negative values for `n`.

---

### Complete function

```
std::function <int(int, unsigned int)> power = [&](int a, unsigned int n)
{
    return (n == 0) ? 1 : a*power(a, n-1);
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe

```
std::function <int(int, int)> power = [&](int a, int n) ....
// ...................^^^^^
```

?

I mean: if `power` is a `std::function` that is initialized with a lambda that receive **two** integers, and is uses as a functional that receive two integers, maybe is the case to declare it as receiving **two** integers, not only one.

Comment: yes it works, thanks, but why I can't simply declare power as auto ?

Comment: @MohamedSaad - not in this case (recursive lambda) because the lambda itself needs to know the type of `power`; using `auto` you enter in a loop where power the lambda needs to know the type of `power` and `power` needs to know the type of the lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Your recursive lambda runs into a problem; it requires the exact variabke it was created in to exist, or it is UB to call it.

```
auto ycomb = [](auto&&f){ return [f=f](auto&&...args){ return f(f, decltype(args)(args)...); }; };
```

this little toy fixes that bug.

```
auto power = ycomb( [](auto&& self, int a, unsigned int n)->int
{
  return (n==0) ? 1 : a*self(self, a, n-1);
});
```

there.

`ycomb` is the ycombinator.  It is famous.

This `power` can be copied around and can outlive the scope of its construction safely.

If you don't like `self(self, args...)` you can reuse ycombinator to make it:

```
auto ycomb0 = [](auto&&f){
  return [=](auto&&...args){
    return f(f, decltype(args)(args)...);
  };
};
auto ycombx_ref = [](auto&& r, auto&& f) {
    return [&r, f](auto&&...args) {
        return f( r(r, f), decltype(args)(args)... );
    };
};
auto ycomb = ycomb0( ycombx_ref );
```

and now the `self` passed to the lambda doesn't itself need to be passed self:

```
auto power = ycomb( [](auto&& self, int a, unsigned int n)->int
{
  return (n==0) ? 1 : a*self(a, n-1);
});
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bce759d77a0dd026).